# android tabview application error

Tags: android, eclipse, tabview

I trying to get the tabview app to work, its working fine in the eclipse emulator, but when trying to install in the device its creating four application each of different activity, that is used in the tab application, did this kind of problem ever occurred to anyone.

some of the code from main activity:

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);
Resources res = getResources(); // Resource object to get Drawables   
TabHost tabHost = getTabHost(); // The activity TabHost   
TabHost.TabSpec spec;  // Reusable TabSpec for each tab  
Intent intent; // Reusable Intent for each tab   
// Create an Intent to launch an Activity for the tab (to be reused)   
intent = new Intent().setClass(this, ArtistActivity.class);   
spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("main").setIndicator("Main", res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_main)).setContent(intent);   
tabHost.addTab(spec);    
intent = new Intent().setClass(this, AlbumActivity.class);   
spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("camera").setIndicator("Camera", res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_camera)).setContent(intent);   
tabHost.addTab(spec);   
intent = new Intent().setClass(this, SongsActivity.class);   
spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("livemap").setIndicator("Live Map", res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_livemap)).setContent(intent);   
tabHost.addTab(spec);   
tabHost.setCurrentTab(0);
```

xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.tablayout.testing"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
   <application android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:name=".TabLayoutDemoActivity"
                   android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
              <activity android:name=".mainActivity"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".cameraActivity"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".mapActivity"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: looking like example :: http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-tabwidget.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am sure there is an issue (not an issue, but a mistake) inside the AndroidManifest.xml file. Mistake is that you have defined all 4 activity as a Launcher activity, instead of that you just have to define only one activity as a Launcher activity.

For example:

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity">

          <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
   </activity>
```

And remove MAIN and LAUNCHER from other activities.

Comment: The structure is correct, anyways i have also posted the xml code

Comment: i have already mentioned in my answer that you have declared MAIN and LAUNCHER intent filter in your all activity, no need for that if you don't want 4 launcher. Just remove it and keep it in only 1 activity.

Answer (score 0):

In manifest file you declared more than one LAUNCHER activity that is not correct. look more [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html)

Comment: Is there anything new in your answer?

Comment: i have just give him a link for Manifest introduction.